# MVC 3 Make a change to an input id and still have the validation work? Multiple identical models in one view

Tags: jquery, razor, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-3

I am attempting to have a multiple model input page where I have 4 iterations of a model in an input form.  Problem here is that all of the inputs are given the same id/name in the html, so only the first set is validated.  With javascript, I was able to modify the ids/names of the inputs, but then all of the *data-val-* attributes are cleared out (or not initialized).  Is there a way I can do this?

It is rendered inside the form like this:

```
foreach (LogEntry sub in entry.SubEntries)
        { @Html.Partial("_ViewSubRow", sub) }
```

But the ones that re made inside that partial don't seem to validate?

Comment: Have you tried a partialView for the input form?

Comment: edited to show how it is used using partials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the validation plugin to reload after changing the id's. Try calling this after you updated the input's IDs:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myForm'));
```

Comment: I also had to add in some validation through JS manually, but this got me headed in the correct direction.  Thank you.